# Google Drive OAuth giving Error: redirect_uri_mismatch on browser

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, redirect

I am trying out google drive api's to do basic upload/download/list files. But I am not sure how to get past authentication.

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets{ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret},                                                                                                  
                                                                                                , scopes
                                                                                                , userName
                                                                                                , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                                , new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result;
```

I have seen various SO posts and I have tried adding and javascript origin and redirect uri in the google dev console as `http://localhost` or as `http://localhost/google_oauth2/callback`. Or is it that the url should be my drive url?

I am a bit confused with redirect uri's. AFAIU, this oauth code will help me access my google drive as my email id is registered in the dev console with this app and secrets are generated. So I don't have a server but just my localhost.

Sorry if this question is silly but I am still learning auth mechanisms. Will be great help if someone could correct me.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth), it states that for every request your application sends to the Drive API, you must include an authorization token. The token also identifies your application to Google. You can find the details of the authorization process in this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet).

Here is a [sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet#step_3_set_up_the_sample) to manage the authorization.

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
                }
```

You'll also need to specify the Open URL for your app, and your preferences on how users create and open files with the app. There are two important things to keep in mind for the Open URL:

- Make sure you give a fully qualified domain name for Open URL, `localhost` does not work.
- The URL must belong to you. After the [app registration](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk#enable_the_drive_api) is complete, you will need to [verify your ownership](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=en) of this URL in order to create a Chrome Web Store listing.

About the redirect URI, it is the callback entry point of the app. The redirect URI specified in the request determines how the authorization code is returned to your application. For example, after end user accepts permissions, "redirect URI" has to be called  to get back to the app. Furthermore, the redirect URI should be different than the initial entry point of the app.You can read the documentation [here](https://www.quora.com/How-does-OAuth-2-0-work).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When you say fully qualified, will ipaddress work? or do i have to create a html page and use that as redirection address? Also, I was selecting web app instead of installed app on the console. I am able to run a console app.